# Help with Mathematical Proof by induction

Tags: induction

I have been asked to prove that:

$$
\frac{1}{3*4} +\frac{1}{4*5} +\frac{1}{5*6}+...+\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)}=\frac{n}{3(n+3)}
 $$

Here is what I have so far but cannot work out how to go further.

RTP: 
$$
\frac{1}{3*4} +\frac{1}{4*5} +\frac{1}{5*6}+...+\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)}=\frac{n}{3(n+3)}
 $$

Proof:

When n = 1 
$$
\frac{1}{(1+2)(1+3)}= \frac{1}{3(1+3)}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{12} = \frac{1}{12} 
$$

Hence true for n = 1

Assume true for n = k 
$$
\frac{1}{3*4} +\frac{1}{4*5} +\frac{1}{5*6}+...+\frac{1}{(k+2)(k+3)}=\frac{k}{3(k+3)}
 $$

When n = (k + 1)

$$
\frac{1}{3*4} +\frac{1}{4*5} +\frac{1}{5*6}+...+\frac{1}{(k+2)(k+3)}+\frac{1}{((k+1)+2)((k+1)+3)}=\frac{k}{3(k+3)}+\frac{1}{((k+1)+2)((k+1)+3)}
 $$ 
$$
=\frac{k}{3(k+3)}+\frac{1}{(k+3)(k+4)}
$$
$$
=\frac{k(k+4)}{3(k+3)(k+4)}+\frac{3}{3(k+3)(k+4)}
$$
$$
=\frac{k(k+4)+3}{3(k+3)(k+4)}
$$

Don't know where to go from here / if I have made any mistakes.

Comment: You could expand out and then factorise $k(k+4)+3$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better without induction:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(k+2)(k+3)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k+2}-\frac{1}{k+3}\right)=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{n+3}=\frac{n}{3(n+3)}.$$

You need to prove that
$$\frac{k}{3(k+3)}+\frac{1}{(k+3)(k+4)}=\frac{k+1}{3(k+4)}$$ or
$$k(k+4)+3=(k+1)(k+3),$$ which is true.

Id est, you have no some mistake.